# Mobile application icon showing in low res instead of hi res

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cab, windows-mobile-6.5

We developed an application for windows mobile 6.5 devices which has an icon which we created with IcoFX based on a hi res .PNG. It has all the icons from 256x256 with alpha transparency down to the lowest resolution and color depth possible. I think we covered all possible combinations of resolutions and color depths (as we some some other windows icons did).

When we see the .exe in windows it seems to use an extremely low resolution and color depth even with large icon view on, doesn't make a difference.
On a windows mobile device it looks more or less but not good enough.

We deploy the app using a .CAB file.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

as I remember, PNG image is used for [start screen icon](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2009/08/11/using-custom-icons-in-windows-mobile-6-5.aspx).

You need multiple images put inside single ICO file for the EXE icon. The ICO file need to be compiled as resource inside the EXE.